# CakePHP array structure from a HABTM query

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I have two tables linked via a HABTM. countries & networks. They are linked together by the countries_networks lookup table.

I need to get all of the countries and all of the associated network ids for each corresponding country. I don't need to go as far as getting the network names, simply getting the ids from the lookup table will suffice.

If I do a find(all) it gives me an array of countries but not in the structure that I need. I need to return something link this, **but I only need Country.countryName and CountriesNetwork.network_id**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Country] => Array
                (
                    [countryName] => Aeroplane
                )
            [Network] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [CountriesNetwork] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [country_id] => 1
                                    [network_id] => 1
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [CountriesNetwork] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [country_id] => 1
                                    [network_id] => 7
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Is there a way of doing this with a findall()? as if I pass fields as an array I always seem to get an unknown column names SQL error.
Or even a custom query? Many thanks in advance to anyone who may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickledegg,

Sounds like you should investigate the Containable behavior.  It will allow you to specify conditions on the joined models like you want, and will return the data formatted in the same manner as the normal find() call.

Check the manual for more information.

Comment: containable did the trick, that combined with the set::extract :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no model for network_countries it's not possible to get those values using `find` or `findAll`. I think the simpliest solution will be to run a custom query to retrieve the data you need.

```
$query = "SELECT country_id, network_id 
FROM countries C LEFT JOIN network_countries NC ON (NC.country_id = C.id)"
$this->Country->query($query);
```

Unfortunately the result returned using that code will be formatted slightly different then `find` results.

Or you could add a model for network countries but I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks RaYell, I have tried that as it happens but it gives me duplicate countries then, I want the format to be 'CountryName', with an array of network ids or names.

Comment: Yes it duplicates the countries because that's how LEFT JOIN is working, however I don't know if you can do it simpler then that. I suppose you could jut get countries and then for each country run a query to get network ids but that will require running a lot of queries instead of one. You could always sort the results by country_id and iterate over the result and just check if country_id of current row has changed, I can't think anything more simple that that I'm afraid